# How Does the ActiveResource Get Call show find(:first) or find(:last) requests?

Tags: sinatra, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeresource

I am developing a Sinatra server that can accept calls from ActiveResource, but can"t determine how to identify Get calls specificying :first or :last.

In Rails 3

```
User.find(:first)  => localhost.com/user.xml
User.find(:last)  => localhost.com/user.xml
```

This works exactly as it should according to the examples in the [ActiveResource  documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-first).

It is clear what path they request (the same one), but it is not clear what happens to the :first or :last elements.  I can not find them in the request object on the Sinatra server.  Does anyone know what happened to those references?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: One thing I learned in testing my app is that Sinatra needs the hash object responses to :first, :last, :all, all wrapped in a array, otherwise an error will be generated in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Code from ActiveResource library

```
  def find(*arguments)
        scope   = arguments.slice!(0)
        options = arguments.slice!(0) || {}

        case scope
          when :all   then find_every(options)
          when :first then find_every(options).first
          when :last  then find_every(options).last
          when :one   then find_one(options)
          else             find_single(scope, options)
        end
      end
```

last and first just methods from Enumerable module